# OpenCV how to imwrite a RGB image

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I write a `RGB` image with the function `cv::imwrite()`? So far all my attempts lead into writing a `BGR` image instead.

My matrix object is a `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `cv::imwrite()` function correctly writes an image file if the input `cv::Mat`is in BGR order (which is the case if you let OpenCV create it). If you created the image by yourself, you have to convert the color ordering before, for example by calling as suggested by bamboove `cv::cvtColor(in, out, CV_RGB2BGR);` if you created an RGB image.

(Pay attention to the color conversion code, it's slightly different from bamboon's.)

Comment: Hi Arkerone, did you know that you can [accept an answer to thank people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188886) This way everyone knows they provided the helpful solution, which gives a warm, fuzzy feeling and beloved rep points! Thanks for considering. :)